# seeking Python lambda function explanation

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, time-series, data-science

I am pretty much beginner with Python and trying to understand [this blogpost](https://towardsdatascience.com/anomaly-detection-with-time-series-forecasting-c34c6d04b24a). 
I could not understood below statement in particular.

```
df['impact'] = [(lambda x: np.where(cut_sort == df['error'][x])[1][0])(x) for x in
                                   range(len(df['error']).
```

`cut_sort` is of type `numpy.ndarray`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which part of that statement do you not understand? it's a complex expression with many parts? lamda? assignment to df['impact']?

Comment: Which parts of the statement *do* you understand? Note that the use of a ``lambda`` function seems superfluous here – it is called immediately.

Comment: the result it that impact gets values from 0 to 7 ... So, i tried simply it and just kept this much portion and i get below output.. i do not understand how that value from 0 to 7 is calculated?                      
 df['impact'] = [(lambda x: np.where(cut_sort == df['error'][x]))(x) for x in
                               range(len(df['error']))]                                                       impact
0    ([0], [0])
1    ([1], [0])
2    ([2], [0])
3    ([3], [0])
4    ([4], [0])
5    ([5], [0])
6    ([6], [3])
7    ([7], [3])
8    ([8], [3])
9    ([9], [4])
10  ([10], [4])

Comment: i understand np.where clause , lambda functions etc..but in this particular format where it is all combined, i do not understand how it returns value from 0 to 7